# Is either one of provided options better?

Tags: forms, login, order

Which one of those solutions is better and why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best determining the behavior of your target audience.

For example, if >50% of your traffic signs in with a google account then place the button at the top. If <50% of your traffic signs in with a google account then place the button at the bottom.

Similarly, what is your preferred method from a product owner point of view? Do you want people to create their own separate accounts for data capture etc or do you want people to link up their google accounts with your application?

Either way an A/B or MVT test can help you determine which variation is best for your user.

I would also suggest making the 'new account sign up' section a lot more obvious if you're expecting to see a lot of new users as your mock-up makes it difficult to find. Again this is dependent on your audience so analytics are your best friend here.